# Spring Cloud Gateway API - Context-path on routes not working

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have setup context-path in application.yml

```
server:
  port: 4177
  max-http-header-size: 65536
  tomcat.accesslog:
    enabled: true
  servlet:
    context-path: /gb-integration
```

And I have configured some routes

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        final String sbl = "http://localhost:4178";

        return builder.routes()
                //gb-sbl-rest
                .route("sbl", r -> r
                        .path("/sbl/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/sbl/(?<segment>.*)", "/gb-sbl/${segment}"))
                        .uri(sbl)).build();
    }
```

I want the API gateway to be reached using localhost:4177/gb-integration/sbl/**
However it is only working on localhost:4177/sbl/**

It seems my context-path is ignored. 
Any ideas how I can get my context-path to work on all my routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already figuered it out by your self, but here is what is working for me:

After reading the Spring Cloud documentation and having tryied many things on my own, I have eventually opted for a route by route configuration. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
.path("/gb-integration/sbl/**")
```

and repeat the same pattern for every route.

```
.path("/gb-integration/abc/**")
...
.path("/gb-integration/def/**")
```

You can actually see this in [spring cloud documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.0.0.RC2/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_fluent_java_routes_api).

The spring clould documentation seems to be in progress. Hopefully, we shall find a better solution.

Comment: Yes I also came to this conclusion also

Answer (score 3):

Detailing on @sendon1982 answer

If your service is exposed at `localhost:8080/color/red` and you want it to be accessible from gateway as `localhost:9090/gateway/color/red`, In the Path param of predicates, prepend the `/gateway`, and add `StripPrefix` as 1 in filters, which basically translates to

> take the requested path which matches `Path`, strip/remove out the prefix paths till the number mentioned and route using given uri and the stripped path

```
my-app-gateway: /gateway
spring:  
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: color-service
        uri: http://localhost:8080
        predicates:
          - Path=${my-app-gateway}/color/**
        filters:
          - StripPrefix=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using yaml file like this

```
spring:  
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: property-search-service-route
        uri: http://localhost:4178
        predicates:
          - Path=/gb-integration/sbl/**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fixed :
```

application.yaml:

```
gateway:
  discovery:
    locator:
      enabled: true
      lower-case-service-id: true
      filters:
        # 去掉 /ierp/[serviceId] 进行转发
        - StripPath=2
      predicates:
        - name: Path
          # 路由匹配 /ierp/[serviceId]
          # org.springframework.cloud.gateway.discovery.DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator#getRouteDefinitions
          args[pattern]: "'/ierp/'+serviceId+'/**'"
```

filter:

```
@Component
public class StripPathGatewayFilterFactory extends 
AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<StripPathGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {
/**
 * Parts key.
 */
public static final String PARTS_KEY = "parts";

public StripPathGatewayFilterFactory() {
    super(StripPathGatewayFilterFactory.Config.class);
}

@Override
public List<String> shortcutFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList(PARTS_KEY);
}

@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        ServerWebExchangeUtils.addOriginalRequestUrl(exchange, request.getURI());
        String path = request.getURI().getRawPath();
        String[] originalParts = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(path, "/");

        // all new paths start with /
        StringBuilder newPath = new StringBuilder("/");
        for (int i = 0; i < originalParts.length; i++) {
            if (i >= config.getParts()) {
                // only append slash if this is the second part or greater
                if (newPath.length() > 1) {
                    newPath.append('/');
                }
                newPath.append(originalParts[i]);
            }
        }
        if (newPath.length() > 1 && path.endsWith("/")) {
            newPath.append('/');
        }

        ServerHttpRequest newRequest = request.mutate().path(newPath.toString()).contextPath(null).build();

        exchange.getAttributes().put(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, newRequest.getURI());

        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(newRequest).build());
    };
}

public static class Config {

    private int parts;

    public int getParts() {
        return parts;
    }

    public void setParts(int parts) {
        this.parts = parts;
    }

}
```

}